# Cloud custodian policy and rds instance count for clusters

Tags: amazon-rds, cloudcustodian

Good evening
Would anyone know if its possible to write a cloud custodian policy that would tag a rds database cluster that has an instance count greater than 2? If it can be done how? I have looked through the documentation etc and can't see how this might be done Thanks

I have researched this without much success